# Bash script works fine in terminal but same script run in Chef fails

Tags: linux, bash, chef-infra

I'm running Chef-client 11.12.8.  I've written a bash script which contains the following line:

```
aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/prod-builds/
```

I'm just using the `awscli` tools to get a list of files from an S3 bucket.  When I run this manually on my terminal (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS), I get this output:

```
2014-10-10 21:27:50   42081271 aragorn-38d5afe23f1fa09a991c4cdbcb8461ed8709d15f.tgz
```

But when chef-client executes a bash script with this same line, using `printf` statements, I see that the bash script outputs only:

```
2014-10-10
```

It seems that the presence of spaces in the command output is confusing chef-client.

Here's the line from my chef recipe that executes the bash script:

```
execute "Download latest build" do
    command "bash /path/to/my/script"
    creates "/file/that/gets/created"
    user "aragorn"
    action :run
end
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

**Update:** As requested, here's a portion of my script:

```
if [ -z "$gitCommitId" ]; then
        # Take a filename like "aragorn-38d5afe23f1fa09a991c4cdbcb8461ed8709d15f.tgz" and extract the commitId from it
        # Note that we take the topmost result
        gitCommitId=$(aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/prod-builds/ | sort -r | head -2 | sed -n '1!p' | awk -F "aragorn-" '{print $2}' | cut -d'.' -f 1)
fi
```

I've confirmed that this line executes (using `printf` statements that output), but the strange thing is that when I execute the command `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/prod-builds/ | sort -r | head -2 | sed -n '1!p' | awk -F "aragorn-" '{print $2}' | cut -d'.' -f 1` directly in my terminal (or manually run the script from my terminal), it works fine.  But when run from chef the `gitCommitId` gets set to nothing.

**Update #2:** I wound up writing a simpler bash script to test differences between Chef and Terminal.  I confirmed that the Chef run outputs different results from calling `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/prod-builds` than when calling it from the terminal.  Specifically, it left out a folder in the S3 bucket that was present in the terminal call.  I still can't explain this.

I wound up using the following line which gave me consistent results by ensuring that only builds were displayed, and no folders:

```
aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/prod-builds/ | grep aragorn | sort -r | head -1 | cut -d'-' -f 4 | cut -d'.' -f 1
```

Special thanks to both @TejayCardon and @StephenC for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: We're going to need more information.  As for this being a problem with Chef, its more likely an issue with ruby, but almost certainly it's a problem with your script.  If we had the whole script we might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Question updated with relevant portion of script.

Comment: I'd add `echo $gitCommitId >> /tmp/testme` right after your `gitCommitId=.....` line.  See what that puts into the file.  I'm guessing (and it's totally that) you are hitting a variable scoping issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I followed this, discovered there was in fact a difference which I still can't explain, and found a different command which works in both.  A strange and disturbing error, but I've been able to resolve my issue.  See my Update #2 for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly occuring in the script, so you need to figure out why the script is failing.

I'd start by changing the `command` attribute to

```
    command "bash -x /path/to/my/script > /tmp/some_file 2>&1"
```

to see exactly what commands that `bash` is executing.

---

> It seems that the presence of spaces in the command output is confusing chef-client.

Nothing you have shown us in the Question supports that conclusion.  (And it is unlikely.  The `execute` resource won't do anything with the output, except (maybe) log it.)

I suspect that the problem is with the script, or one of the commands it runs .... or the assumptions that it is making about environment variables, current directory, etc.

---

**UPDATE**

So the problem seems to be in this pipeline:

```
   aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/prod-builds/ | \
       sort -r | \ 
       head -2 | \
       sed -n '1!p' | \
       awk -F "aragorn-" '{print $2}' | \
       cut -d'.' -f 1
```

I'd start by looking to see if the first command in the pipeline is producing any output onto stdout.  (I suspect that the problem is that the environment variables that the `aws` command needs have not been set.)

Comment: Thanks for the guidelines. I'm taking a look at the output and noticing new things. I think you're right this is not a Chef issue.  I'll post a portion of my script in my answer.

Comment: Thank you again for your assistance. It made me realize I needed to isolate this line in its own bash script.  Per my Update #2, this still caused different results, but now I could observe them directly. I wound up using a slight variation on the original script.

Comment: I also want to clarify that I'm using AWS IAM Roles, so the environment variables aren't an issue.  Ultimately, your suggestion -- change the highlighted line -- was correct, so I'll mark your answer as correct.  Thanks again!